Is there a way to see previous new music notifications from the Music app?
I regularly get notifications on my iPhone about new releases from artists I am interested in. I'm often not in a position to listen to that new song immediately. I would like to be able to find that notification - and all the others like it - later so I can listen to the new songs.
Notification centre does seem to keep older notifications, so often by the time I am ready to spend some time listening, that message has gone.
Is there a way to get a list of "historic" notifications from the music app on iPhone and/or Mac?
